# prerequisites to learn GraphQL and best course to learn

Tags: graphql

are there any prerequisites to learn GraphQL and can someone suggest the best course to learn graphql?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view:
SQL knowledge must needed one. Other than this no special techniques are needed for learning GraphQL. Initial stage you must go through the official documentation for better understanding.
official documentation Link: https://graphql.org/learn/

Comment: I do not think, that SQL is a must-have (in my opinion you do not need any SQL knowledge to learn GraphQL - and that's another point: the question is quite opinion-based).

Comment: GraphQL is a query language. So from my point of view without SQL knowledge understanding GraphQL is difficult one.